# Show/Hide http/ftp links?

Tags: javascript, html

I have links in HTML that I wish to hide as shown below:

```
007 - Dalla Russia con amore (1963) Full Blu Ray ....
http://somewhere.example.com/1
007 - L'uomo dalla pistola d'oro (1974) Full Blu Ray 1....
http://somewhere.example.com/2
007 Operazione Tuono (1965) Full Bluray 43.9 GB...
http://somewhere.example.com/3
http://somewhere.example.com/4
007 Vendetta privata (1989) Full Blu ray ....
http://somewhere.example.com/5
```

I want this result:

```
007 - Dalla Russia con amore (1963).....
007 - L'uomo dalla pistola d'oro (1974) Full B...
007 Operazione Tuono (1965) Full Bluray 43...
007 Vendetta privata (1989) Full Bl...
```

I would like to have a code that will allow me to view each title individually:

```
007 - Dalla Russia con amore (1963) Full Blu Ray 39,6 GB AVC DTS-HD 5.1
http://somewhere.example.com/1
07 - L'uomo dalla pistola d'oro (1974) Full B...
007 Operazione Tuono (1965) Full Bluray 43...
007 Vendetta privata (1989) Full Bl...
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide some kind of starting point.. what code generates what you have already?

Comment: Oh ! You need a script to beautify your personal DVD library manager ?

Comment: i have yet html page, but i want hide only the http links to have html page output with http links hidden. Is possible?

Comment: Should we guess the html mark-up you're using for this?

Comment: What is your html, how are you generating the markup, can you use jquery?

Comment: my html is just this: http://pastebin.com/DB4vYKxE

Answer (score 1):

Well if that's the case I would look into using jquery's

hide: http://api.jquery.com/hide/
and 
show: http://api.jquery.com/show/

**Otherwise** you could use javascript to set the `display` property from `none` to `block`.

Comment: ok..i can use jquery but when i click on show/hide buttons i want hide/show only the links (http, www, ftp). How can i modify its code?

Comment: Try using jquery's `closest` function to `show` or `hide` the closest link when a certain title is clicked. Without any html, javascript, or effort/input into this post, I can really only point you in the right direction.

Comment: my html is very simple http://pastebin.com/DB4vYKxE Can u help me to insert the jquery code into head section?

Comment: Well for starters, you'll need to format you html properly (`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML`) with opening and closing tags around each element. There needs to be some structure.

Comment: ok..but can u paste me the jquery code, please? I try to insert it to test html page